# Math Database For Problem Descriptions In An App.

Tags: probability, math-software, education, fractions, absolute-value

I am developing an app for kids and they will have a variety of problems from percentage problems, absolute value problems, negative number problems, fraction problems, etc. I was hoping to have a description of how to do each type before they began. Does anyone know of a good database where I could get all the descriptions from and then just cite that source?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](http://www.commonsensemedia.org/mobile-app-lists/best-math-apps) , [here](http://www.teachscienceandmath.com/2010/08/25/12-free-mobile-math-apps-for-the-ipod-touch/) and for new ideas [here](http://www.camelotlearning.com/math-curriculum)

Since you have more grace period:  These are list of links that will give you an idea on the topic that you are considering:

http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/journal/suurtamm.pdf 
http://www.mathman.biz/ 
http://www.icme10.dk/proceedings/pages/ICME_pdf-files/tsg14.pdf 
http://www.nctm.org/resources/content.aspx?id=17109 
http://jumpmath1.org/

http://www.edu.gov.on.ca/eng/literacynumeracy/inspire/research/WW_problem_based_math.pdf 
http://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/

(Particularly the last two links are interesting)

Sites that are like Khanacademy 
http://www.mathtv.com/videos_by_topic 
http://www.learnerstv.com/ 
http://videolectures.net/ 
http://www.learner.org/ 
http://www.brightstorm.com/

http://www.academicearth.org/ 
http://ocw.mit.edu/ 
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/

(Particularly the last three are of high quality)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind for me is [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/#browse), and it's not clear if Khan breaks the problems down into the same units that you desire for your app. In general, Khan already subsumes a huge portion of the demand for these kinds of flash-card-eqsue, math-training resources online. I'm sure they will move to an app soon if not already, and Khan also covers tons of other domains outside of math. I have no idea if you need permission or anything to cite their pages in your app.

Comment: It is Khan Academy (Kahn should be corrected to Khan in your answer)

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. I fixed it.